# Проблема с компиляцией TypeScript в phpstorm (.d.ts файлы)

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, компилятор, typescript

Настроил watcher. Работает всё хорошо, за исключением такго момента.
При каждом проходе он размножает мне .d.ts файлы, а не перезаписывает.
Может мне кто-то подсказать что с этим делать?

[image: Скрин]

То, что сейчас в аргументах вотчера:

```
--out $ProjectFileDir$/js/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js --sourceMap -d $FileName$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно для такого хватает настроек по-умолчанию. Попробуй удалить вотчер и создать заново. Либо попробуй подставить в аргументы:

```
--sourcemap $FilePath$
```

Вообще, я бы советовал писать в папке /src, а компилированные складывать в /js.

Comment: "Вообще, я бы советовал писать в папке /src, а компилированные складывать в /js.". Согласен. С дэфолтными настройками не дублирует. И всёравно ведь интересно, почему он себя так вёл... Спасибо за помощь.